# Changing string in cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have cells with data like these:

```
ABCD123XYZ  
MPOP345MLU
.  
.  
.  
.
```

What I want to do is, to remove the 3rd and 4th character from all these cells, hence giving

```
AB123XYZ  
MP345MLU
```

How do I do this in VBA?

I have no idea about this language, and if someone can guide me in the right direction, it'd be great :)

I understand I have to:

1. Declare 2 string variables st1 and st2
2. Store data from cell A1 into the variable st1
3. Copy all but the 2nd and 3rd char into str2
4. Output Str2 into B1
5. Move to A2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need VBA for this.  Just use a formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,2) & MID(A1,5,9999)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using Replace() formula where A1 is the cell which has the text. You can simply copy the formula down.

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,3,1,""),3,1,"")
```

**VBA CODE**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=REPLACE(REPLACE(RC[-1],3,1,""""),3,1,"""")"
        .Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for sharing pearls from your vast store of VBA-related knowledge in this answer and as comments to other answers. Cheers.

Comment: +1 Sid - nice work, I cant believe no one has posted a dirty old loop solution!!! You could do away with the autofill if you like:  `With Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1)
    .Formula = "=REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,3,1,""""),3,1,"""")"
    .Value = .Value
End With`

Answer (score 1):

use the "mid" function

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String

str1 = Cells(1, 1) '"ABCD123XYZ"
str2 = Cells(2, 1) '"MPOP345MLU"

Cells(1, 2) = Mid(str1, 1, 2) & Mid(str1, 5) 'yield AB123XYZ
Cells(2, 2) = Mid(str2, 1, 2) & Mid(str2, 5) 'yield MP345MLU
```

Comment: This is very low quality answer.  Please add more details and explanation.  Remember that you are answering not for this specific question but for posterity so others can use this question/answer as a reference.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@DougGlancy's got your answer already,
but if you really want to use VBA:

```
Sub substr_example()
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1:B100").FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=LEFT(RC[-1],2)&MID(RC[-1],5,LEN(RC[-1])-4)"
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for giving an alternative. bernie, it is not necessary for the R1C1 ref style to be checked since you are already specifying `.FormulaR1C1`. Also would suggest this formula instead of hardcoding 100 or any other number in MID(). `=IF(LEN(A1)>3,LEFT(A1,2)&MID(A1,5, LEN(A1)-4),"")`

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Yes! You are absolutely correct. Thank you for your comment. I have incorporated your suggestions by editing the answer.